# how to post on users wall

Tags: php, mysql, facebook

I have made a facebook application in php mysql, now i want to pass updates from the application to the users wall, its  not a like button but an activity that i want to share on user wall. much like:

xxx just had pizza for lunch, via logUrLunch App

i hv managed to connect to facebook and got user id from facebook as follows:

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if ($user) {
  try {
    // Get the user profile data you have permission to view
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
    $uid = $facebook->getUser();
    session_start(); 
    $_SESSION['userID'] = $uid;

    //print_r($user_profile);
    //echo "</pre>";
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    $user = null;
  }
} else {
  die('<script>top.location.href="'.$facebook->getLoginUrl().'";</script>');
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

below code surely works: even if you dont have permission it will try to get them

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
  'secret' => 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
));
$user = $facebook->getUser();
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');


if( array_key_exists('publish_stream', $permissions['data'][0]) ) {
                // Permission is granted!
                // Do the related task
                //$post_id = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=>'Hello World!'));
                  $post_id = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', $attachment);

            } else {
                // We don't have the permission
                // Alert the user or ask for the permission!
                echo "Click Below to Enter!";
                header( "Location: " . $facebook->getLoginUrl(array("scope" => "publish_stream")) );
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You must first be granted the `publish_stream` [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/policy/examples_and_explanations/Extended_Permissions/).

Then you can use the [`stream.Publish`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/fbjs/streamPublish/) method in the Facebook Javascript SDK with the `auto_publish` parameter set to `true`, or check out the 'publishing' section of the graph API docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/) which can also be used to accomplish this.